# Open default web page resized and in full screen - kiosk mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a simple need I believe but I can't seem to find all of the pieces while searching to get the result I'm desiring. I have an ASP.NET application with a *single* page that will be hosted in IIS (`Default.aspx`).

I simply want the window to open in a fixed height and width *and* be in kiosk / full screen mode. I can currently open the window resized as follows:

```
<body onload="resizeWindow();">
```

and:

```
   function resizeWindow() {
      var width = 600;
      var height = 400;
      window.resizeTo(width, height);
      window.moveTo(((screen.width - width) / 2), ((screen.height - height) / 2));
   }
```

However, without using a `window.open` call using JS which allows setting the parameters for kiosk mode, I'm not sure how to marry the needs together.

I would also prefer a `jQuery` solution if it exists (i.e. using `$(document ).ready()` maybe?), but a raw `JS` solution like I have is fine too.

Does anyone know how to make my single page on this site open in a fixed size and in full size / kiosk mode too?

Comment: AFAIK you can only do this with `window.open`, and not to an existing window.

Comment: Is there a way to use `window.open` on launch then?

Comment: Yes, that's not a problem.  Just put the `window.open()` command inside a `document.ready` event handler.  The only problem with this approach (and I see it as a major issue) is that most popup blockers will stop it working.  You'd need some actual user activity to open the new window, like clicking a link or button.  This may be a job for the old-fashioned landing page :)